# Asking for a date to be input by user using cx_Oracle in Python Pandas vs. PL/SQL

Tags: python, date, cx-oracle

I have a query that works perfectly in PL/SQL where I ask for a date to be inputted by the user which says:

```sql
select * from X (X is a table in a database called DATABASE which I am connected to)
where date_=TO_DATE('&Enter_Date','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I tried to replicate it in Python and cx_Oracle using the following:

```
import cx_Oracle

db2 = cx_Oracle.connect('/@DATABASE')
positions = """

SELECT * FROM X 

WHERE date_=TO_DATE('&Enter_Date','YYYY-MM-DD')

"""
```

and I get an error. : ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0.  If I actually code in the date such as '2022-06-30' it works but I want the user to be able to input it.

Appreciate any help you can give me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The "&" in your string is processed by SQL*Plus and treated as an input value, but this does not happen with Python. Instead you have to ask for input from the user using the `input()` built-in and then pass that through to the database. Like the following:

```py
# import oracledb # python-oracledb
import cx_Oracle as oracledb

conn = oracledb.connect(user="USER", password="PASSWORD", dsn="DSN")
user_val = input("Enter Date: ")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from x where date_ = to_date(:val, 'YYYY-MM-DD')",
               val=user_val)
```

You can also use Python routines to convert the value entered by the user into a Python date and pass that through to the database (avoiding the to_date() call) if that is desirable.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried it - it gave me a can't find a table error.  I also tried to take the : otut before the val and then it found the table but it gave me a variable error.

Comment: The colon is needed because it is 'bind variable' syntax, see the [doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html).  Removing it caused Python to trip up before the statement was sent to the DB.  You should verify you are connected as the correct user to the correct database, and also verify your table and column names.

Comment: I got it to work.. I could use my code that I had and made 2 changes.